# std::make_pair : cannot convert 'ch' (type 'char') to type 'char&&'

Tags: c++, c++11

What's is wrong with the following code:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::pair< char, unsigned > > vec;

    for( unsigned i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
    {
        char ch = 0;
        unsigned number = 0;

        do {
            ch = i;
            number = i;

        } while( std::find( vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::make_pair< char, unsigned >( ch, number ) ) != vec.end() );

        std::cout << ch << number << '\n';

        vec.push_back( std::make_pair< char, unsigned >( ch, number ) );
    }
}
```

It does compile nicely with:

```
g++ test.cxx
```

but fails with:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cxx                                                                                                              /tmp
test.cxx: In function 'int main()':
test.cxx:21:98: error: no matching function for call to 'make_pair(char&, unsigned int&)'
test.cxx:21:98: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:65:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/vector:61,
                 from test.cxx:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:268:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr std::pair<typename std::__decay_and_strip<_Tp>::__type, typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T2>::__type> std::make_pair(_T1&&, _T2&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:268:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cxx:21:98: note:   cannot convert 'ch' (type 'char') to type 'char&&'
test.cxx:25:69: error: no matching function for call to 'make_pair(char&, unsigned int&)'
test.cxx:25:69: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:65:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/vector:61,
                 from test.cxx:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:268:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr std::pair<typename std::__decay_and_strip<_Tp>::__type, typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T2>::__type> std::make_pair(_T1&&, _T2&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:268:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cxx:25:69: note:   cannot convert 'ch' (type 'char') to type 'char&&'
```

Comment: Why on earth would you pass template arguments to `std::make_pair` in the first place..?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Instead of explicitly specifying the template arguments to `make_pair<>()` this way:

```
std::make_pair< char, unsigned >( ch, number )
```

Just let them be deduced:

```
std::make_pair( ch, number )
```

---

**EXPLANATION:**

The rationale behind this guideline is found in the way `std::make_pair<>()` is defined, and in the way template argument deduction works for universal references. From Paragraph 20.3.3/8-9 of the C++11 Standard:

> `template <class T1, class T2>`
> `pair<V1, V2> make_pair(T1&& x, T2&& y);`
>
> *Returns*: `pair<V1, V2>(std::forward<T1>(x), std::forward<T2>(y));`
> where V1 and V2 are determined as follows: Let `Ui` be `decay<Ti>::type` for each `Ti`. Then each `Vi` is `X&` if `Ui` equals `reference_wrapper<X>`, otherwise `Vi` is `Ui`. [ *Example*: In place of:
>
> `return pair<int, double>(5, 3.1415926); // explicit types`
>
> a C++ program may contain:
>
> `return make_pair(5, 3.1415926); // types are deduced`
>
> —*end example* ]

Here, `T1` and `T2` are *meant* to be deduced. By explicitly specifying the template arguments yourself, you're getting on the way of `make_pair<>()`'s type deduction machinery to produce the correct return type, forcing the instantiation of a function which accepts an rvalue reference to `char` and and rvalue reference to `unsigned`:

```
... make_pair(char&&, unsigned&&)
```

However, you are not providing rvalues in input, because `ch` and `number` are lvalues. This is what the compiler is complaining about.

---

**ALTERNATIVE:**

Also notice, that you can *implicitly construct* an `std::pair` object, which saves your from calling `make_pair<>()` at all:

```
vec.push_back( { ch, number } );
```